# Приложение в Docker контейнере не видит сетевых ресурсов. UnknownHostException

Tags: java, docker, apache-kafka

Всем привет, начинаю разбираться с Docker контейнерами, но не могу решить одну проблему.

Есть приложение с Kafka Consumer запущенное в Docker контейнере. Приложение использует сетевые ресурсы, но в контейнере их не видит? Полагаю их нужно как-то прописывать отдельно? Прошу помочь разобраться, как это сделать.

Dockerfile прилагаю:

```
FROM openjdk:8

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y maven

WORKDIR /pg_importer

# Prepare by downloading dependencies
ADD pom.xml /pg_importer/pom.xml
RUN ["mvn", "dependency:resolve"]
RUN ["mvn", "verify"]

# Adding source, compile and package into a fat jar
ADD src /pg_importer/src
RUN ["mvn", "install"]

 EXPOSE 5432
 EXPOSE 8081
 EXPOSE 2181
 EXPOSE 9092

COPY target/pg_importer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/pg_importer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/opt/pg_importer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar", "10", "//localhost:5432/ulk", "root", "root", "http://wn.ua/ULKTest/solution/config/metadata_full.xml", "http://kafka-utils01.ua:8081", "kafka01.ua:9092,kafka02.ua:9092,dkafka03.ua:9092", "kafka01.ua:2181,kafka01.ua:2181,kafka01.ua:2181"]
```

Выбрасывает ошибку:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: wn.ua
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
```

Comment: А как вы запускаете образ?

Comment: 1) через Dockerfile в Idea; 2) либо в консоли docker start my_container

Comment: Вы говорите что контейнер использует внешние ресурсы, но при этом он у вас никак не общается с внешним миром. Предположу что вам надо замапить порты. Вариант первый - создать образ и запустить его  командой docker run -p hostport:containerport image. Либо прописать в докерфайле, если я сейчас не ошибаюсь команду EXPOSE с желаемыми портами

Comment: Нашел вот такое описание EXPOSE для Dockerfile https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose. В понедельник опробую. Спасибо.

Comment: Добавил EXPOSE с портами, увы не помогло :(

Comment: Потому что я действительно ошибся. По ссылке же написано


The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are intended to be published. To actually publish the port when running the container, use the -p flag on docker run to publish and map one or more ports, or the -P flag to publish all exposed ports and map them to high-order ports.


Так что сначала попробуйте создать образ build'ом и потом запускать его с флагом -p

Comment: запустилось с указанием dns  $docker run --dns 10.15.34.166 05fe46be5c8a. Все сетевые ресурсы видит кроме jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ulk

Comment: Попробуйте добавить явное указание порта -p5432:5432

Comment: тоже не помогает

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает, с dns зайти на //localhost: не получится

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вся проблема решилась с помощью --net=host -it без прописывания портов и dns.

Пример запуска: sudo docker run --net=host -it 857fbcaab9da

Более детально в этом топике: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482716/using-docker-to-launch-web-app-cant-connect-to-postgresql-db